# Should I include tests and .pyc files when building package with setuptools?

Tags: python, packaging, setuptools

I'm trying to install a local package using `pip install .` in a conda environment. Everything looks okay, except that when I run this command, there are .pyc files being included by default (I'm guessing this is due to the build process). Explicitly excluding them in MANIFEST.in doesn't help. First of all, is this a problem? The setup.py is actually very simple. Mainly, the only relevant thing is `include_package_data = True` that I need in order to include some static files.

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
...
    include_package_data = True,
...
)
```

and this is the MANIFEST.in

MANIFEST.in

```
recursive-include <my-project>/static *
global-exclude *.pyc
global-exclude .git
```

Another question: Should I include my test folder (`recursive-include <my-project>/test/ *`)
in the installed package? I have some tests using nose and other client-side tests which are included as static files. What is the recommended way to deal with tests in this case?

Comment: I do not quite understand the first question. You're installing a package and worried that `.pyc` files appear at the location where it's being installed? It's normal, `.py` files are precompiled by `setuptools` automatically on installation.

Comment: That's what I thought but then I saw some repositories that insisted in ignoring .pyc files.

Comment: Could you link an example? I thought that the only things that are installed by default are `.py` files in the packages passed to `setup()`'s `packages` keyword. Moreover, `MANIFEST` isn't about installation, it governs the distribution (what files are included in the archive when you run `python setup.py sdist`).

Comment: Sure. First example from Google: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/MANIFEST.in

Comment: I think in this case the author includes *everything* from `docs`, and then excludes `.pyc` and `.pyo` files. You don't need to do that with the package itself. E.g. [my project](https://github.com/fjarri/reikna/blob/develop/MANIFEST.in) where I only include `.rst` files and one `.py` file from `docs`, works just fine.

Comment: Great. Thanks. Do you have some suggestion on the second question?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The discussion is getting long, so I'll just write up my thoughts here.

> Everything looks okay, except that when I run this command, there are .pyc files being included by default (I'm guessing this is due to the build process).

Python sources are precompiled on installation, and `.pyc` files are put along with the `.py` files in the installation location by `setuptools`. It's a normal behavior.

> Explicitly excluding them in MANIFEST.in doesn't help.

`MANIFEST.in` governs distribution, not installation. That is, it tells `setuptools` which files to include in the archive when `python setup.py sdist` is run. It is commonly used to include documentation, tests, license and other accompanying files that are part of the package, but are not actually installed. The files that *are* installed (in addition to `.py` files) are specified in the `package_data` keyword argument to `setup()`.

> Another question: Should I include my test folder (recursive-include /test/ *) in the installed package?

There are two approaches possible:

1. Include tests in the *distribution*, but not install them. To do this, you put them in a separate folder and include all required files (including the `.py` ones) explicitly in the `MANIFEST.in`. As an example, see this excerpt from the [manifest](https://github.com/fjarri/reikna/blob/develop/MANIFEST.in) of one of my projects:

   ```
   recursive-include test *.py
   include test/pylintrc
   include test/.coveragerc
   ```
2. Include tests in the package itself, so that you can run them as `import package; package.test()` (for instance, `numpy` does that). No need to tinker with the `MANIFEST.in`, just put them in the main package directory (as a subpackage or whatever) and treat them as a regular subpackage/module.

*Edit:* answering the additional questions:

> What about the option test_suite (e.g. nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/setuptools_integration.html)?

I haven't used this particular option (maybe I should), but I have a similar setup in [another project](https://github.com/fjarri/peval/blob/master/setup.py), which also makes `python setup.py test` available — used by Travis.CI for automatic test runs. Since I'm a fan of `py.test`, it requires some interfacing; for `nose` it would look simpler.

In general, if you can do it, do it, it's a good thing to have (for continuous integration in particular).

> Does including tests as a subpackage cause issues?

Well, `numpy` and many other packages are doing fine. The only downsides that I see are:

- the size of the installation is increased (but in our age of terabyte HDDs it is probably not that important)
- tests are somewhat harder to run from the command line
- you don't have a clear separation between the package itself and the tests (very arguable)

In conclusion, I don't have anything against it and may very well use this kind of setup for my next project.

> The Python Packaging User Guide includes an example that does this: packages=find_packages(exclude=['docs', 'tests*'])

This is done to include all Python packages for installation, but skip the folders with `.py` files that are not supposed to be installed as packages. You can either do that, or supply the list of packages manually. It's just an example of how to implement the scenario `1` from my answer above. In the scenario `2` your `tests` folder will be *inside* your main package folder, and will be picked up by `find_packages()` normally.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What about the option `test_suite` (e.g. http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/setuptools_integration.html)? Does including tests as a subpackage cause issues? The Python Packaging User Guide includes an example that does this:     `packages=find_packages(exclude=['docs', 'tests*'])`

Comment: Added my comments to the main answer.

Comment: `test_suite` is deprecated

Comment: "the size of the installation is increased (but in our age of terabyte HDDs it is probably not that important)": AWS lambda has a deployment package size limit of 50 MB. Only a few years ago it was ~10MB. With Pandas / Matplotlib, you were getting there pretty quickly.